# Difficulties implementing the JQuery Ui Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I've implemented the jQuery slider UI in the page below but it doesn't seem to be initialising.

[Test Page](http://licf.ronaldboadi.com/test2.html)

I loaded it up in Firebug and I got the following error:

```
$("#slider-range").slider is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

slide: function( event, ui ) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the JQuery UI Library. Only included the `jQuery` is **not** enough.

You can use CDN to include the UI library.

1. JQuery CDN:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. Google CDN:

   ```
   <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   ```

Include one of those, or, even better, read this [Getting Started Docs](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started).

**UPDATES**

You have to include the CSS files, to properly view the UI elements. Include the following CSS file

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
```

See your slider in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/SLvtx/)

Comment: I've done it but its still not working - I've updated http://licf.ronaldboadi.com/test2.html

Comment: @CJS, You also have to include the UI CSS files, read the getting started I linked

Comment: @CJS, Check my update, I have included the css link to insert and also a demo of your working file